# Git - .gitignore file for all different developers

Tags: git

I am trying to set up on the "origin" a .gitignore that every time a new repo clones the "origin" - it will get that .gitignore file as well.

All my searches lead me to "global" git ignore which appears to be a way to configure this for all repos with the same user (I want it to be "global" to all "clones" of the same origin repo).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `.gitignore` file to the repository and commit it. All clones will have it. This is very common, perfectly legitimate practice by the way.